# how to pass multidimensional array from php to ajax jquery with images

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'demo.php',
dataType: 'json',
success:function(result)
{
$obj[] = JSON.parse(result);
$('#id1').html($obj[1][1]);
$('#name1').html($obj[1][2]);
php file:=>
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
$rows[] = $row; }
echo json_encode($rows);
```

I do not know how can i pass $rows to ajax.($rows contains 2 rows and 4 Colums with 2 images). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this by the following

```
var object = {};
object.id = 34;

JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: json file contain real images... not only strings

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({

```
type: 'POST',
url: 'demo.php',
dataType: 'json',
success:function(data)
{
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        $('#id1').html(data[i].obj);
    }
}
```

});

If this doesn't work post your data which you are getting after success function

Comment: do console.log(data) after success function and post your data here so that i can understand clearly